# How to handle ConnectTimeoutException Android

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know how to handle a ConnectTimeoutException? i'm posting variables to a url using AsyncTask but my internet connection is shocking so i'm recieving null data back because of a ConnectTimeoutException. What are the best ways to handle this for example if time out occurs try run again etc i have not had this problem before so don't have a clue how to handle but i feel it needs handling to improve user experience. so any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to let your `Activity` know you got a `ConnectTimeoutException`

Catch this exception in your AsyncTask and send a message to your `Handler` (then do whatever you want)

Just for information, AsyncTask aren't designed for long running operation, if so you should use a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)

Answer (score 0):

this is how you shoud check for the network status

```
 ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                //execute your AsyncTask method
            } else {

               //maketoast..."No network connection available"
            }
```

Comment: FYI this code is from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) if you want more information

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate class called Activity helper, and implement it in your async task for any class that you make in which requires a webservice call.

```
public class ActivityHelper {
    public static final String NETWORK_CONNECTION_MESSAGE = "No Network Connection. Please make sure you have a Network Connection.";


public static boolean isNetworkPresent(Context applicationContext){
    boolean hasService = false;
    NetworkInfo info=(NetworkInfo)( (ConnectivityManager)applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
    hasService = (info==null || !info.isConnected())?false:true;
    return hasService;

}
}
```

call Activity Helper in "doInBackground" Method kinda like this..

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Message message = new Message();
    String type = "";
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         ActivityHelper.onUserInteraction(getApplicationContext());
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LocationType.this,
                "Connecting to server", "Please wait...", true, true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            if(!ActivityHelper.isNetworkPresent(getApplicationContext())){
                message.what = ActivityHelper.NONETWORKCONNECTION;
                return null;
            }
} catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().getName(),
                    "Exception Message");
        }
        return null;
    }
```